# Can't change style : display using getelementbyclassname

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
document.getElementByClassName('xyz').style.display = 'none';
```

I am unable to hide class content.

Comment: with `getElementsByClassName` you are getting `HTMLCollection` so try  `document.getElementsByClassName('xyz')[0].style.display = 'none';`

Comment: Next time Press F12 and read the console logs. It should point you to at least one mistake you did there.

Comment: Do you have one, or more than one, elements with the class `xyz`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 14):

`document.getElementsByClassName` return an array like object. you can use following script for this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('xyz')[0].style.display = 'none';
```

or if you want to hide all `.xyz` element

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("xyz");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
function show(){
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('elem');
console.log(element);
element[0].style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.elem {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div> visible
  <div class="elem">hidden
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="show()">click</button>
</div>
```

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array, you can't directly set the style of element like it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like:
`let elem = document.getElementsByClassName('xyz')[0];`

`elem.style.display = 'none';`

Answer (score 1):

[document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) elements is a live HTMLCollection of found elements.

```html
<div class="xyz">

test content
</div>
<button  type="button" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('xyz')[0].style.display = 'none';">Hide Content </button>
<button  type="button" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('xyz')[0].style.display = '';">Show Content </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $("#afficher_commentaire").change(function(){ 
        // alert("OK");
            if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
              var commentaire_date_fin_fourniture = document.getElementsByClassName("commentaire_date_fin_fourniture");
              for (var i = 0; i < commentaire_date_fin_fourniture.length; i++) { 
                  commentaire_date_fin_fourniture[i].style.display='block';
                  }
            }
            else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
              var commentaire_date_fin_fourniture = document.getElementsByClassName("commentaire_date_fin_fourniture");
            for (var i = 0; i < commentaire_date_fin_fourniture.length; i++) { 
                commentaire_date_fin_fourniture[i].style.display='none';
                }
            }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Working version

```js
hide = function(){
document.getElementsByClassName('xyz')[0].style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<input class="xyz" type="text"/>

<button onclick="hide();">Click to hide!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do things this way, then of course first you need to spell `getElementsByClassName` correctly; you saw this error in the console, right? Then, you need to know that `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like things; you saw that in the documentation, right? So you have to loop over it, or take the first element with `[0]`, or whatever.

But in general, it's bad practice to retrieve elements from the DOM like this and set their styles directly. Instead, take advantage of CSS, which will do 90% of the work for you. Here, I'd use a single higher-level class which controls the behavior, and just set that:

```
<main id="main">
  <div class="xyz"></div>
<main>
```

Then write your CSS as

```
main.hide-xyz .xyz { display: none; }
```

To hide the `xyz` element, then you need a single JS statement:

```
document.getElementById("main").classList.add("hide-xyz");
```

To remove it:

```
document.getElementById("main").classList.remove("hide-xyz");
```

Or toggle it:

```
document.getElementById("main").classList.toggle("hide-xyz");
```

Once you wrap your head around this style, you'll find yourself writing **much** less JavaScript that needs to all kinds of DOM lookups and loops and setting of styles.

Comment: only works in case you have an id one could link to, if used only classes this would not work (for example in a ng-repeat)

Comment: The question was using Class Name not ID.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` always returns an **array** like **object**. Specify the **array[0]** number.

**Typescript**

```
let hiddenLocales = document.getElementsByClassName('localeMatch') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
let hideParentNode = hiddenLocales[0]?.parentElement;
hideParentNode?.remove(); // Remove the element
hideParentNode?.style.display = "none"; // Hide the element
```